# cURL headers not being received correctly

Tags: php, curl

### Overview

I'm trying to send an XML file via cURL.

Everything is working *except* for the headers, which aren't being sent correctly.

Why are they not being received?

---

### Code

**test.php**

```
$xml = file_get_contents("test.xml");

//These are the CUSTOM HEADERS being set in an array for later:
$data = array(
    'x-meta-feed-type: Latest',
    'x-meta-feed-parameters: feed params',
    'x-meta-default-filename: '.time().'.xml',
    'x-meta-game-id: f790722',
    'x-meta-competition-id: c420',
    'x-meta-season-id: 2014',
    'x-meta-gamesystem-id: SUD_CL',
    'x-meta-matchday: 7',
    'x-meta-away-team-id: t2578',
    'x-meta-home-team-id: t764',
    'x-meta-game-status: 11',
    'x-meta-language: en',
    'x-meta-production-server: local',
    'x-meta-production-server-timestamp: '.time(),
    'x-meta-production-server-module: 1',
    ' x-meta-mime-type: text/xml',
    'encoding: UTF-8'
);

//set URL
$url = 'http://www.example.com/receive.php';

// Get the curl session object
$session = curl_init($url);

// set url to post to
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

// Tell curl to use HTTP POST;
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data);

// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

// Tell curl not to return headers, and return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

// allow redirects
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
if (curl_errno($session)) {
    print "Error: " . curl_error($session);
} else {
    // Show me the result 
    echo $response;
    curl_close($session);
}
curl_close($session);
```

**receive.php**

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

$post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');

$posts = array (
    'feedType' => isset($headers['x-meta-feed-type']) ? $headers['x-meta-feed-type'] : '',
    'feedParameters' => isset($headers['x-meta-feed-parameters']) ? $headers['x-meta-feed-parameters'] : '',
    'defaultFilename' => isset($headers['x-meta-default-filename']) ? $headers['x-meta-default-filename'] : '',
    'deliveryType' => isset($headers['x-meta-game-id']) ? $headers['x-meta-game-id'] : '',
    'messageDigest' => md5($post_data),
    'competitionId' => isset($headers['x-meta-competition-id']) ? $headers['x-meta-competition-id'] : '',
    'seasonId' => isset($headers['x-meta-season-id']) ? $headers['x-meta-season-id'] : '',
    'gameId' => isset($headers['x-meta-game-id']) ? $headers['x-meta-game-id'] : '',
    'gameSystemId' => isset($headers['x-meta-gamesystem-id']) ? $headers['x-meta-gamesystem-id'] : '',
    'matchday' => isset($headers['x-meta-matchday']) ? $headers['x-meta-matchday'] : '',
    'awayTeamId' => isset($headers['x-meta-away-team-id'])?$headers['x-meta-away-team-id']:'',
    'homeTeamId' => isset($headers['x-meta-home-team-id']) ? $headers['x-meta-home-team-id'] : '',
    'gameStatus' => isset($headers['x-meta-game-status']) ? $headers['x-meta-game-status'] : '',
    'language' => isset($headers['x-meta-language']) ? $headers['x-meta-language'] : '',
    'productionServer' => isset($headers['x-meta-production-server']) ? $headers['x-meta-production-server'] : '',
    'productionServerTimeStamp' => isset($headers['x-meta-production-server-timestamp']) ? $headers['x-meta-production-server-timestamp'] : '',
    'productionServerModule' => isset($headers['x-meta-production-server-module']) ? $headers['x-meta-production-server-module'] : '',
    'mimeType' => 'text/xml',
    'encoding' => isset($headers['x-meta-encoding']) ? $headers['x-meta-encoding'] : '',
    'content' => $post_data
);

exit(print_r($posts));
```

**Output**

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 05 Oct 2015 11:13:20 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u1
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

Array
(
    [feedType] => 
    [feedParameters] => 
    [defaultFilename] => 
    [deliveryType] => 
    [messageDigest] => 144ce144c73a12ea51a03ac1ef1256e5
    [competitionId] => 
    [seasonId] => 
    [gameId] => 
    [gameSystemId] => 
    [matchday] => 
    [awayTeamId] => 
    [homeTeamId] => 
    [gameStatus] => 
    [language] => 
    [productionServer] => 
    [productionServerTimeStamp] => 
    [productionServerModule] => 
    [mimeType] => text/xml
    [encoding] => 
    [content] => File Content
) 1
```

Comment: Did you tried to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `true` also?

Comment: did you get solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use `var_dump` on the `$headers` object (retrieved via `apache_request_headers`), I see that all the header tags have had their first letters capitalised:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 05 Oct 2015 11:30:20 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u1
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

array(24) {
  ["Connection"]=>
  string(5) "close"
  ["Expect"]=>
  string(12) "100-continue"
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ["Content-Length"]=>
  string(5) "90166"
  ["Encoding"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["X-Meta-Mime-Type"]=>
  string(8) "text/xml"
  ["X-Meta-Production-Server-Module"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["X-Meta-Production-Server-Timestamp"]=>
  string(10) "1444044620"
  ["X-Meta-Production-Server"]=>
  string(6) "server"
  ["X-Meta-Language"]=>
  string(2) "en"
  ["X-Meta-Game-Status"]=>
  string(2) "11"
  ["X-Meta-Home-Team-Id"]=>
  string(4) "t764"
  ["X-Meta-Away-Team-Id"]=>
  string(5) "t2578"
  ["X-Meta-Matchday"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["X-Meta-Gamesystem-Id"]=>
  string(6) "SUD_CL"
  ["X-Meta-Season-Id"]=>
  string(4) "2014"
  ["X-Meta-Competition-Id"]=>
  string(4) "c420"
  ["X-Meta-Game-Id"]=>
  string(7) "f790722"
  ["X-Meta-Default-Filename"]=>
  string(26) "opta-1444044620-bIb24r.xml"
  ["X-Meta-Feed-Parameters"]=>
  string(11) "feed params"
  ["X-Meta-Feed-Type"]=>
  string(6) "Latest"
  ["Accept"]=>
  string(3) "*/*"
  ["Host"]=>
  string(19) "example.com"
  ["User-Agent"]=>
  string(109) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"
}
```

While this is strange - and I'm curious as to why this happens, as the headers were not capitalised when sent - the solution is to simply change the receiving page to check for the capitalised custom headers as they are case-sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Add header Content-Type to application/xml or text/xml in header $data as you are sending xml data in post.

```
$data = array(
    'x-meta-feed-type: Latest',
    'x-meta-feed-parameters: feed params',
    'x-meta-default-filename: '.time().'.xml',
    'x-meta-game-id: f790722',
    'x-meta-competition-id: c420',
    'x-meta-season-id: 2014',
    'x-meta-gamesystem-id: SUD_CL',
    'x-meta-matchday: 7',
    'x-meta-away-team-id: t2578',
    'x-meta-home-team-id: t764',
    'x-meta-game-status: 11',
    'x-meta-language: en',
    'x-meta-production-server: local',
    'x-meta-production-server-timestamp: '.time(),
    'x-meta-production-server-module: 1',
    ' x-meta-mime-type: text/xml',
    'encoding: UTF-8',
    'Content-Type : application/xml'
);
```

Comment: The XML data is working fine... it was the custom headers that weren't coming through correctly.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan have checked by putting header ?